# can not hide X-Powered-By with expose_php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to hide my php version in response headers and for that I changed **expose_php** to **off** but it does not work
[image: My php.ini file]

and I added **Header unset X-Powered-By** to my htaccess file but in did not work either
can you guide me for that?

Comment: What file have edited? What webserver are you using? What version of php are you using?

Comment: my php.ini have been edited, i'm using apache web server and my php version is 7.4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I added `Header unset X-Powered-By` to my htaccess file but in did not work either

Depending on which *group* the `X-Powered-By` header has been set, you may need to use the `always` condition (instead of the default `onsuccess`). For example:

```
Header always unset X-Powered-By
```

You can also try removing the header from within PHP itself. For example:

```
<?php
header_remove('X-Powered-By');
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the in my localhost
The Value off didn't work for me instead Off worked for me, looks like its case sensitive

Note: Server Restart Is Necessary

Comment: I changed it to Off but it didn't make any difference